# Regular expression for identical characters despite line breaks and spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

How can I create a regular expression in python that matches consecutive identical characters, regardless of whether line breaks or spaces are in between? The number of identical characters should be adjustable.

examples (e can be any character except newline or space):

match: eee, e e e,
e
e
e

no match: ebe, e b e, e e

attempts:

```
(\S)[\s\n]*\1{2}
(\S)(?:\s|\n)*\1{2}
```

Comment: Simply `e\s*e\s*e`?

Comment: The syntax is [`(\S)(?:\s*\1){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/PiFO1a/1) (`\n` is contained already in `\s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\A\s*(\S)(?:\s*\1\s*)+\Z
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bKpoRp/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\A`: asserts position at start of the string
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\S)`: Match any non-whitespace character and capture in group #1
- `(?:\s*\1\s*)+`: Match same value we captured in group #1 surrounded with 0 or more whitespaces on either side. Repeat this group 1 or more times
- `\Z`: asserts position at the end of the string

Comment: I have modified your regex to fit my needs now. (\S)(?:\s*\1\s*){2}

Comment: Sure if you need min 3 repetitions then `{2}` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can match

```
(\S)(?:\1|\s)*\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8TIdP/1)

The regular expression reads, "Match a character other than a whitespace (`\S`), save it to capture group 1 (`(\S)`), then match zero or more characters, as many as possible (`*`), each such character being the contents of capture group 1 (`\1`) or (`|`) a whitespace character (`\s`), then match the contents of capture group 1.

Note that while you referred to "line breaks or spaces" I have assumed you want to include other whitespace characters, such as tabs, and that while you said the repeating character "can be any character except newline or space" I have assumed you do not want it to be other whitespace characters as well, such as tabs. `([^ \r\n])(?:\1| |\r|\n)*\1` would satisfy your explicitly-stated requirements.

I have also assumed that there might be one or more matches within a string.